# Failure to invoke Lambda cross-account for creating a Lambda-backed custom resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

I'm trying to implement a use case, where a Lambda function can be invoked across-account through an *AWS CloudFormation* template.

I'm deploying an *AWS CloudFormation* stack in `account B`, which has a custom resource that invokes that Lambda function defined in `account A`.
I have created a cross account role for Lambda in `account A` with `account B` as a trusted entity. Also, the user in `account B` has been attached with a policy that allows it to assume this role.
Unfortunately, the stack creation fails the access error.

Would appreciate any help. Here's my template for *account B*:

```
{
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
  "Resources": {
    "GetNwInterfaces":{
      "Type": "Custom::GetNwInterfaces",
      "Properties": {
        "ServiceToken": "arn:aws:lambda:ap-northeast-2:XXXXXXXXXX:function:getini2",
        "region": "us-west-2",
        "uid" : "01100"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What's the exact error you're getting?
Can you share the other template (i.e. the one being used account A)?

Answer (score 1):

Create the Lambda function in account A with the proper permissions, eg, use this cloudformation template:

```
Parameters:
  OtherAccountId:
    Type: String

Resources:
  TestFunction:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      Runtime: python2.7
      Handler: index.handler
      Role: !GetAtt TestRole.Arn
      Code:
        ZipFile: !Sub |
          from botocore.vendored import requests
          import json


          def send(event, context, responseStatus, responseData, physicalResourceId):
              responseUrl = event['ResponseURL']

              print responseUrl

              responseBody = {}
              responseBody['Status'] = responseStatus
              responseBody['Reason'] = 'See the details in CloudWatch Log Stream: ' + context.log_stream_name
              responseBody['PhysicalResourceId'] = physicalResourceId or context.log_stream_name
              responseBody['StackId'] = event['StackId']
              responseBody['RequestId'] = event['RequestId']
              responseBody['LogicalResourceId'] = event['LogicalResourceId']
              responseBody['Data'] = responseData

              json_responseBody = json.dumps(responseBody)

              print "Response body:\n" + json_responseBody

              headers = {
                  'content-type' : '',
                  'content-length' : str(len(json_responseBody))
              }

              try:
                  response = requests.put(responseUrl,
                                          data=json_responseBody,
                                          headers=headers)
                  print "Status code: " + response.reason
              except Exception as e:
                  print "send(..) failed executing requests.put(..): " + str(e)

          def handler(event, context):
              print event
              print context

              responseData = {}

              send(event, context, "SUCCESS", responseData, "CustomResourcePhysicalID")

  CrossAccountPermission:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
    Properties:
      Action: lambda:InvokeFunction
      FunctionName: !Ref TestFunction
      Principal: !Ref OtherAccountId

  TestRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          -
            Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - lambda.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - sts:AssumeRole
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: AllowAccess
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: 2012-10-17
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - "logs:*"
                Resource: "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*"
```

The `CrossAccountPermission` record is the important one here, there we grant access to account B.

In account B, test it with the following template:

```
Parameters:
  LambdaArn:
    Type: String

Resources:
  CustomResourceTest:
    Type: Custom::Demo
    Properties:
      ServiceToken: !Ref LambdaArn
```

There is an additional possible gotcha here: The user/role that is running cloudformation in account B also needs permission to execute the Lambda function, if you are running CF with an admin user that shouldn't be an issue as you would have `lambda:*` permissions on resource `*` anyway.

Comment: Hi Paulo, Found an interesting thing during this exercise. In addition to cross account access role in Account A with full lambda access and permission for role assumption from account B, we have to add one more layer of access to the lambda function directly that is being invoked from the CLI which made the whole thing work---aws lambda add-permission --function-name test_lambda --region us-east-1 --statement-id id-123 --action “lambda:InvokeFunction” --principal 1234567890

Comment: @schaganti can you please explain what that does?